# How to make a tabs if clicked it will refresh or reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

how do I click tabs to refresh or retrieve new data using the ant design framework https://ant.design/components/tabs/

this my picture tabs
[image]

and this code

I have made the handle change function, maybe what is wrong with my logic? ... if it is wrong how to correct it, so if clicked on the tab it will refresh or retrieve new data

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import { CustomTabPane } from "../../components/CustomTabDashboard";
import OrderListWaitingInDelivery from "../OrderListWaitingInDelivery";
import OrderListWaitingFinish from "../OrderListWaitingFinish";
import OrderListWaitingNotSent from "../OrderListWaitingNotSent";
import OrderListWaitingNotPay from "../OrderListWaitingNotPay";
import OrderDetailsDashboard from "../OrderDetailsDashboard";
import OrderDetailsCancel from "../OrderDetailsCancel";
import OrderListWaitingCancel from "../OrderListWaitingCancel";


class CustomerOderNavigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isShowOrderDetailsDashboard: false,
      orderId: null,
      activeKey: "1"
    };
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
  }

  actionShowOrderListWaiting = () => {
    this.setState({
      isShowOrderDetailsDashboard: !this.state.isShowOrderDetailsDashboard
    });
  };

  actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard = (orderId) => {
    this.actionShowOrderListWaiting();
    this.setState({
      orderId: orderId
    })
  };

  handleChange = (selectedkey) => {
    this.setState({ activeKey: selectedkey });
    console.log("change callback");
  };



  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs activeKey={this.state.activeKey} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <CustomTabPane
          key={"1"}
          tab={
            <span
              onClick={() =>
                this.setState({
                  isShowOrderDetailsDashboard: false
                })}
            >{"Belum Bayar"}</span>}
          my_prop={
            this.state.isShowOrderDetailsDashboard === false ?
              (<OrderListWaitingNotPay
                actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard={this.actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard}
                tabsNotPay={1}
              />) : (
                <OrderDetailsDashboard
                  orderId={this.state.orderId}
                  actionShowOrderListWaiting={() => this.actionShowOrderListWaiting()}
                  tabsNotPay={1}
                />)
          }
        />
        <CustomTabPane
          key={"2"}
          tab={<span
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({
                isShowOrderDetailsDashboard: false
              })}>{"Belum Dikirim"}</span>}
          my_prop={
            this.state.isShowOrderDetailsDashboard === false ?
              <OrderListWaitingNotSent
                actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard={this.actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard}
                tabsNotSent={2}
              /> : (
                <OrderDetailsDashboard orderId={this.state.orderId}
                  actionShowOrderListWaiting={() => this.actionShowOrderListWaiting()}
                  tabsNotSent={2}
                />
              )
          }
        />
        <CustomTabPane
          key={"3"}
          tab={<span
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({
                isShowOrderDetailsDashboard: false
              })}>
            {"Dalam Pengiriman"}
          </span>}
          my_prop={
            this.state.isShowOrderDetailsDashboard === false ?
              <OrderListWaitingInDelivery
                actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard={this.actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard}
                tabsInDelivery={3}
              /> : (
                <OrderDetailsDashboard orderId={this.state.orderId}
                  actionShowOrderListWaiting={() => this.actionShowOrderListWaiting()}
                  tabsInDelivery={3}
                />
              )
          } />
        <CustomTabPane
          key={"4"}
          tab={<span
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({
                isShowOrderDetailsDashboard: false
              })}>{"Selesai"}</span>}
          my_prop={
            this.state.isShowOrderDetailsDashboard === false ?
              <OrderListWaitingFinish
                actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard={this.actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard}
                tabsFinish={4}
              /> : (
                <OrderDetailsDashboard orderId={this.state.orderId}
                  actionShowOrderListWaiting={() => this.actionShowOrderListWaiting()}
                  tabsFinish={4}
                />
              )
          } />
        <CustomTabPane
          key={"5"}
          tab={<span
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({
                isShowOrderDetailsDashboard: false
              })}>{"Batal"}</span>}
          my_prop={
            this.state.isShowOrderDetailsDashboard === false ?
              <OrderListWaitingCancel
                actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard={this.actionShowOrderDetailsDashboard}
              /> : (
                <OrderDetailsCancel orderId={this.state.orderId}
                  actionShowOrderListWaiting={() => this.actionShowOrderListWaiting()}
                />
              )
          }
        />
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomerOderNavigation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call a function to update data, in your `handleChange`

```
updateTab1 = () => {
  alert('update tab 1')
};

updateTab2 = () => {
  alert('update tab 2')
};

handleChange = (selectedkey) => {
  this.setState({ activeKey: selectedkey });

  if (selectedKey === '1') {
     this.updateTab1();
  } else if (selectedKey === '2') {
     this.updateTab2();
  }
  // more conditions here
};
```

Comment: ×
TypeError: _this.updateTab2 is not a function
CustomerOderNavigation._this.handleChange
src/containers/CustomerOrderNavigation/index.jsx:47
  44 |  if (selectedkey === '1') {
  45 |    this.updateTab1();
  46 | } else if (selectedkey === '2') {
> 47 |    this.updateTab2();
     | ^  48 | }
  49 |  this.setState({ activeKey: selectedkey });
  50 |  console.log("change callback");

Comment: How to ? what should I give ... to refresh or retrieve new data

Comment: don't you know how to call a function?

Comment: updateTab1 = () => {
    window.location.reload ();
  } I made it like this ... besides this is there anything else

Comment: what do you want to refresh? the whole page?

Comment: actually not all pages, but only tabs

Comment: make a call to the api to get new data, inside those functions.

Comment: the problem for calling data is not here, but inside each component

Comment: besides the window location is there anything else?

Comment: because you are reloading the window, as I said in my other comment you need to call a function that updates the data. move the functions from their own components and add them to this component and pass them as props.

Comment: can you give an example

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of ant Design you are using, you could do:
`<CustomTabPane forceRender`
or
`<Tabs destroyInactiveTabPane`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `destroyInactiveTabPane` prop on Tabs.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs
      destroyInactiveTabPane={true} // add this prop
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as it's native to antd.